# How sound does it make when a tree falls?

Tags: word-request

I was going through a footpath there was a tree, suddenly that began falling but it waited for a moment , then it started falling, yet again it waited for a moment, then it started falling, like this it was constant for some moments. Finally the tree fell completely .

**How was there the sound of falling the tree?**

That tree all fell, waiting but if a tree falls without waiting, what would you call that sound too?

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot understand your question. Are there words in your language for what you are looking for? Maybe someone on this site would understand. I can't think of a specific word for the sound of a tree falling, whether or not it falls immediately or one step at a time.

Comment: Yes that exists in my language

Comment: You could try editing your question and adding the words in your language. If anyone on this site speaks your language, you might find someone who can help.

Comment: Someone says on the site that here you can't ask any translation of the language. It's only for the English language

Comment: I am sorry, you are probably right about the rules. But I don't know any specific English words like this. You might say a tree "crashed down suddenly with a loud bang" or that a "tree groaned and creaked as it gradually fell." But I don't know if that helps.

Comment: I think that "crash" is the most common term. "A tree fell with a crash" is quite typical.

Comment: In English, there is no word for the sound a tree makes when falling.  A good author will make do with some evocative [onomatopoeia](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/onomatopoeia) like *"crash", "bang", "thud", "roar"*, etc.  or else something more creative, *"the tree fell with a sound like a train crash."*

Comment: Ziya, it's OK to mention the word from your native language if it helps explain the English word you are looking for. We are not a translation service, but we can help you find the idiomatic way to explain a concept in English. See this post on meta for more information: [Is it ok ask for translation words?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3149/)

Comment: It depends on whether there is anyone there to here it.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the tree would have made a number of different sounds as it fell.

When wood bends, it tends to "creak" and "groan."

When it bends too much, it "snaps" and "cracks."

Depending on how large the tree was, how fast it was falling, and what the ground was covered with, when it finally hit the ground, it may have landed with a "thud," a "bang," a "crash," a "boom."

Answer (score 0):

"The sound of the falling tree" or "the sound of the tree falling" would describe the sound while the tree was falling.  "The sound of a tree hitting the ground" would be the final sound.